# codeigniter pushing values into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am having a multidimensional array, which I got from db results

```
$property['property'] =  $this->property->property_filter($data);
```

Array looks like this

```
array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#78 (20) {
        ["property_id"]=>
        string(2) "27"
        ["user_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["type_id"]=>
        string(2) "13"
        ["contract_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["city_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["area_id"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["date_added"]=>
        string(10) "2015-04-29"
        ..............goes on...
```

I want to push a value manually in array.. I tried like this

```
  $property['property'][0]['image']="lankahomes_23_2.jpg";
```

I am not getting any errors. but it's not working.
Any suggestions or any better way to push vales into multi-dimensional array in codeigniter.

Comment: $property['property'][0]->image = "lankahomes_23_2.jpg";

Comment: @splash58 . that works, can you please give me some explanation, if possible. please add that as answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the dump.

**`$property['property']`** is **`array`** of **`objects`**,
so **`$property['property'][0]`** is **object**, 
and its property should be reference by **`->`** not **`[ ]`**.

So correct code is:

```
$property['property'][0]->image = "lankahomes_23_2.jpg";
```